# Is there a way to set the order of images appear on a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a personal home inventory database. On one of the forms called Update Location, there is an image of the floor plan of the condo and then on top an image of location flag (pin icon) indicating where the location is in the condo.

For example:

- Room: Den
- Location: Top of desk
- Flag is at point

  - LeftCoordinate.Value (X) and
  - TopCoordinate.Value (Y).

I have a toggle button then allows me to click on the map and sets a new X and Y position for the flag based on where I click on the map.

However, when I do this the flag image disappears behind the floor plan image until I click on another part of the form and then it is in the right spot. I am fairly new to VBA (especially in Access). Is there a way I can get the flag image on top?

I have tried searching Google but all the examples tend to be for one image and never an image over another image.

```
Private Sub Draw_Location_Icon()

Me.Painting = False

LeftStartPoint = 5292 ' 3.675"  Left corner of floor plan attachment
TopStartPoint = 837   ' 0.5826" Top corner of floor plan attachment
IconHalfWidth = 180   ' 0.125"  Half the icon width
IconFullHeight = 360  ' 0.250"  Full height of icon

Me.Location_Icon.Visible = False

If Me.LeftCoordinate.Value > 0 Or Me.TopCoordinate.Value > 0 Then
    Location_Icon.Left = LeftStartPoint - IconHalfWidth + Me.LeftCoordinate.Value
    Location_Icon.Top = TopStartPoint - IconFullHeight + Me.TopCoordinate.Value
    Me.Location_Icon.Visible = True
End If

Me.Painting = True

End Sub
```

As I stated currently the floor plan image is on top of the flag when I move the location flag but it is fine once I click on another part of the form. I would like the form to refresh with the floor plan on bottom and flag on top.

I am sure I am missing a small item to either set the orders of the image or perhaps I can get the VBA code to "click" somewhere else on the form and make the flag appear on top?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know it unfortunately is not possible to control the z-axis position of form controls at runtime.

Comment: A fragile but workable solution is to make a series of image controls named Layer1 through Layer4, and use the `Bring To Front` button to arrange their z-order appropriately. Assign the Flag to Layer1, the Floorplan to Layer2, and so on.

Comment: The graphics will move on the form when it becomes an executable. I have provided a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YT3njFVa_o&feature=youtu.be) to show the issue I am having.

One workaround may be if I can set a "click" to another part of the form after I move the image but I am not sure how to code that.